# Opening an activity from a notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-activity

I have an activity called "A" with two buttons. Each button opens other new activities "B" and "C", the activity "A" is in onPause state.
The activity "C" has a viewpager with 3 pages

This application can receive notifications.

Clicking on a notification received, open the activity "C".

This functions correctly in the following way:

```
//...
    NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
...
Intent intent =new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activityC.class);
        intent.putExtra("hello", notificationData);
```

This is my problem:

I want that when you click the notification received, if my application is showing the activity "A" or "B" or the application is in background, to close and open the activity "C"

If the application is showing the activity "C" leads to a page of the ViewPager (`pager.setCurrentItem (2);`)

Several days I've been reading, I've tried several ways, using `android:launchMode="singleTop"` defining `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` ...but always without success

I'm going crazy with this ...

Someone could help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than launching Activity from C, send a broadcast when notification is clicked which shall be received by your Activity A and then A shall launch your Activity C.

You can try setting FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP for activity C so that if C is already on top , it shall receive the intent.

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is define where you were at the end.
here is how i would handle this:

> Make a class and extend it from Application class

define a variable here, it can be boolean, enum,int ,etc...
when you enter any of those activities, change that parameter.

> in OnDestroy of each activity reset that particular variable to its default value.
>
> In your service before making the intent, check which state you were at last and make your intent based on that.

```
public class MY_APPLCIATION extends Application {
    public static Boolean ActivityAIsRunning=false;
    public static Boolean ActivityBIsRunning=false;
}
```

override onResume and onDestroy of both activities :

```
public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {
    // ......
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        MY_APPLCIATION.ActivityAIsRunning=false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        MY_APPLCIATION.ActivityAIsRunning=true;
    }
}
```

ActivityB :

```
public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {
    // ......
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        MY_APPLCIATION.ActivityBIsRunning=false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        MY_APPLCIATION.ActivityBIsRunning=true;
    }
}
```

now there is an important note which you should pay attention to :

> You should define the intent when you are creating the notification !

you should have another activity ( let's called it MY_NOTIFICATION_ACTIVITY ).
and the notification should always go to this activity.
now in that activity check which boolean is set and then call the desired activity (ActivityA or ActivityB or ActivityC). Do not forget that in your manifest you should make ActivityB singleTop too !!!

> *** ANOTHER SIMPLE METHOD

another simple method is that you update the notification in OnResume of each activity.
by entering each activity you change the intent to that desired activity and make the same notification and update the last notification.